# Can procedures take user run-time input as parameters?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I'm quite new to plsql and I have what I think is a fairly basic question.

I've created the following procedure which works perfectly as I want it:

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_list_similar_recipes(idr_p IN recipe.idr%TYPE)

AS
  idr_row recipe%ROWTYPE;
  v_similarity NUMBER;
  v_title VARCHAR2(200);

BEGIN  
  FOR idr_row IN (SELECT * FROM recipe ORDER BY idr) LOOP
    SELECT recipetitle
    INTO v_title
    from RECIPE
    WHERE IDR = idr_p;
    v_similarity := func_similarity(idr_p, idr_row.idr);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Similarity between ' || v_title || 'idR(' || idr_p || ') and '|| idr_row.recipetitle || '(idR' || idr_row.idr || '): ' || v_similarity);
    END LOOP;
END proc_list_similar_recipes;
```

And to test it/get output from it I'm making simple anonymous blocks like so:

```
SET SERVEROUPUT ON
SET VERIFY OFF
ACCEPT prompt_idr PROMPT 'Please enter a valid id'
DECLARE
  prompt_idr number :=&prompt_idr;
BEGIN
  proc_list_similar_recipes(prompt_idr);

END;
/
```

But the specification of the problem states that my procedure should "prompt the user for an value"? Is it possible to do this without having an additional anonymous block?

Comment: Nothing to do with your question, but what jumps out at me is the fact that you're selecting the title of the recipe of concern *inside the loop*. Once the title is obtained, it does not change for the duration of the procedure. There is no reason to have it being reselected over and over again. And you should skip over the cursor row where the idr is the same as the idr being passed in as the parameter. Hopefully the function returns a value that shows the recipe is very similar to itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But the specification of the problem states that my procedure should "prompt the user for an value"?

**The fact is that PL/SQL is not interactive.**

If your requirement is strictly to **prompt** and **accept** values from **user**, then **PL/SQL** is not a good solution. A PL/SQL code is **compiled** and stored in the **database**, so it is **not an interactive**.

Also, **&** is used for variable substitution in `SQL*Plus`, and it is not a good/feasible idea to provide SQL*Plus as an user interface to the user to input values.

I strongly recommend a frontend **application** for this kind of requirement. PL/SQL is not interactive, and not suitable here. SQL*Plus as an interface will be a nightmare for a user.